# Find all solutions of $e^{e^z}=1$ in the complex space.

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification

Find all solutions of $e^{e^z}=1$ in the complex space.

**Attempt:**

$e^{e^z}=1$. Assuming $e^z$ is a complex number, I will start off solving $e^z=e^{x+yi}=1$: $e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)=1\Rightarrow \sin y=0\Rightarrow y=\pi k$. Now, $e^x>0\Rightarrow \cos y =0,\pm 1$. Then $y$ has to be $2\pi k$, and $x$ has to be $0$. Assuming I don't miss solutions (which I really can't tell), I set: $$e^z=2\pi k i$$.
$e^x(\cos y+i\sin y)=2\pi k i\Rightarrow y={\pi\over 2}+\pi m, \sin y=\pm 1$.

Now $\pm e^x =2\pi k$ (Am I allow to do this?). Now I get $x=\ln (2\pi k)$
but $\ln$ only work with $k\ge 1$ in the Real Numbers, so taking $\pm e^x=2\pi k (k>0)$ instead seems to solve the issue.

I get: $z=ln(2\pi k)+i({\pi \over 2}+\pi m), (k,m)\in \Bbb{Z}_+\times \Bbb{Z}$. Checking it gives the required results. My only insecurity is all the branches idea. Would you guide me?

Comment: nothing complicated : $e^a = e^b \Leftrightarrow a = b + 2 i k \pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ so $e^{e^z} = e^{0} \Leftrightarrow e^z = 2 i k \pi, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ but for $k \ne 0$ :  $\pm 2 i |k| \pi = e^{\ln( 2|k|\pi) \pm i \pi/2}$ so $e^z = \pm 2 i |k| \pi  \Leftrightarrow  z =\ln( 2|k|\pi)  \pm i \pi/2 + 2 i m \pi, m \in \mathbb{Z}$ overall the solution is $z =\ln( 2|k|\pi)  \pm i \pi/2 + 2 i m \pi, (k,m) \in \mathbb{Z^*}\times\mathbb{Z} $

Answer (score 2):

Well, you must have $e^{z}$ be an integral multiple of $i 2 \pi$.  So,
$$
e^{z} = i 2 \pi n, \quad \mbox{$n$ an integer}.
$$
Now examine the possible definitions of the various branches of the natural log, so you can extract $z$ from he above equation.